# Use two parameter in one method

Tags: angular, google-maps, methods

l am try to build IONIC app using angular . My app is content on Google map and including data json api for airports coordinates shows on map . l want to change the color of icon of airports depending on delay Index . For that i used tow parameters on one method and that method is responsible on icons airport and coordinates of airports .

method name `addMarker()`

My code :

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  points: Array<any> = [];
  Data: any;
  map: GoogleMap;
  mags_icons: string;
  DelayAvg: any

  constructor(private http: HTTP) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
    this.getData();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }

  getData() {

    this.http.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", {}, {}).then(data => {


      // coordinates 


      this.Data = JSON.parse(data.data);
      this.points = Object.keys(this.Data)
        .map(key => this.Data[key].airport.position)
        .map((position) => ({
          lat: position.latitude,
          lng: position.longitude
        }))
        console.log(this.points)

        this.points.forEach((point) => {

          this.addMarker(point);
        });



        // icons 

      this.DelayAvg = Object.keys(this.Data)
        .map(key => this.Data[key].stats.arrivals)
        .map((arrivals) => (
         arrivals.delayIndex

        ))
        console.log(this.DelayAvg)

      this.DelayAvg.forEach((icons: any) => {

        this.addMarker(icons)


        let mag = icons;

        switch (mag) {
          case 0:
          case 1.9:
            return this.mags_icons = './assets/icon/green.png';
          case 2:
          case 3.5:
            return this.mags_icons = './assets/icon/yellow.png';
          case 3.6:
          case 5:
            return this.mags_icons = './assets/icon/red.png';
          default:
            return "blue";
        }
      });



      console.log(this.mags_icons)

    })

  }

  addMarker(point,icons) {
    return this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: icons,
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: point
    });
  }



}
```

but the problem is l got error under `this.addMarker(icons)` and `this.addMarker(point);`

error is `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

any idea please ?

Comment: The method addMarker defined for accepting two parameters. But you're calling every time the method only with one parameter. Method signature is addMarker(point,icons)

Comment: So what is a best way ?

Comment: You have to process the JSON object in one place and you can achieve this only with function call addMarker().

Comment: i did it and when i run my app l got error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'airport' of undefined` you can check my code here  (https://i.imgur.com/K8XZUlt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following way to achieve your goal. There in the map function return the new point object with location and icon property.

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  points: Array<any> = [];
  Data: any;
  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
    this.getData();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
  }

  getData() {
    this.http.get("<URL>").
      subscribe((data) => {
        this.Data = JSON.parse(data.data);
        this.points = Object.keys(this.Data)
          .map(key => this.Data[key])
          .map((data) => {
            var point = {};
            point["location"] = { lat: data.airport.position.latitude, lng: data.airport.position.longitude };
            switch (data.stats.arrivals.delayIndex) {
              case 0:
                break;
              case 1.9:
                point["icon"] = './assets/icon/green.png';
                break;
              case 2:
                break;
              case 3.5:
                point["icon"] = './assets/icon/yellow.png';
                break;
              case 3.6:
                break;
              case 5:
                point["icon"] = './assets/icon/red.png';
                break;
              default:
                point["icon"] = './assets/icon/blue.png';
            }
            return point;
          });
        this.points.forEach((point) => {
          this.addMarker(point);
        });
      });
  }

  addMarker(point: any) {
    return this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: point.icon,
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: point.location
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: your code working fine , but the problem is the icons is not show by my customize ! , he is shows by default for google map icon . You can check console https://i.imgur.com/aPgr7aF.png

Comment: I made the mistake, Actually default: point["icon"] = "blue"; value also should be loaded from assets. What about other icons?

Comment: i fixed , i used if statement allowance Switch and now working fine . thank you

Comment: Oh..the issue with switch case. Every time it comes to default block because of we are not using break statement. Try to use the updated answer.